# How to prove that a function obeys a certain functional equation

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, dynamical-systems

I saw this equation in a book and It was used as part of calculating something else in [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=f9XiBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA244&pg=PA244#v=onepage&q&f=false) and [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=RdXSBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA181&pg=PA181#v=onepage&q&f=false) Can I get any help about this equation

the statement is this:

suppose that:
$$f: R\times R \rightarrow R$$
$$k: R\rightarrow R$$
we assume function G exits such that:
$$f(x,k(x)+z) = f(x,k(x)) + G(x,z)z$$
prove that G is calculated by this formula:
 $G(x,z) = \int_{0}^{1} D_x(f(x,k(x)+yz)dy$

My problem is that the writers of the links I gave above use this equation and there is no proof or reference for that I want to know how this can be proved

Comment: What is $k$? What is $f$?

Comment: What does $K:R\times R$ mean? You have to put a lot more thought into your presentation, if you expect anyone to be able to understand, much less answer, your question. In fact, I don't even see a question.

Comment: F should be infinitely differentiable for example you can  suppose that $f(x,z) = sin(x+z^2)$ and $k(x)=exp(x)$

Comment: I have updated the question @gerry-myerson

Comment: Sorry, it's still not clear. You introduce $F$ and $K$, but never refer to them after that. I suppose $R$ is the reals, but who knows? You introduce $f$ and $k$ – are they supposed to be the same as $F$ and $K$? Are you supposing $G$ exists, or are you asserting that $G$ exists, or are you asking whether the $G$ given by the formula with the integral satisfies the equation displayed above it? The quetion still needs a lot of work.

Comment: hope it's more clear now @GerryMyerson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $h(s)=F(x,k(x)+sz)$. By the chain rule, its derivative is
$$
h'(s)=(D_yF)(x,k(x)+sz)\cdot z,~~ \text{ which means } ~~ h'(s)=\left.\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial y}\right|_{y=k(x)+sz}.
$$
Now integrate this equation over $[0,1]$ and use that $z$ is constant to get
$$
F(x,k(x)+z)=h(1)=h(0)+\int_0^1h'(s)\,ds=F(x,k(x))+\left[\int_0^1 (D_yF)(x,k(x)+sz)\,ds\right]\cdot z.
$$
The notation in your claim seems slightly skewed in this light.